# Is 忍者/忍び also used for women?

Tags: word-choice, words

I was discussing with a friend, who asked me if `忍者` is also used for women, or if `くノ一` is used/preferred. I know `者` means "person", so it seems to be neutral; and [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%8D%E8%80%85) defines the word using `者`, which again seems to suggest it can be used for women; but I noticed in **Basilisk** female characters are called `女忍者`.

I wasn't able to find something definite about this: can `忍者` be used for women, or does it sound strange/wrong?

Edit: Another friend of mine said that `忍び` is used for men, but [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%8D%E3%81%B3) doesn't say anithing about that, and it being an abbreviation for `忍びの者` it does seem neutral; not sure if it can also be used for women.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I hate to sound realistic here, but the concept of the female ninja is basically all fictional to begin with.  If I am not mistaken (which I do not think I am), there exists no record so far that proves the existence of a female ninja in real life that performed the same tasks as a male ninja such as surveillance and destruction.

That being said, the word 「忍者{にんじゃ}」 can technically refer to both male and female ninjas **in fiction**, but when the gender is of importance to the story, the words 「女忍者{おんなにんじゃ}」 and 「[くノ一]{くのいち}」 are often used.

The word 「くノ一」 itself is as old as you expect a Japanese word to be, but it has only been several decades since it started to be used to refer to a female ninja in fiction.  Before that, 「くノ一」 was only a slang word for 「女」.

「く」, 「ノ」 and 「一」 are the components/strokes of the kanji 「女」.  That is in the correct stroke order, too.

In conclusion, 「忍者」, 「忍{しの}び」 and 「忍びの者{もの}」 are all gender-neutral.  If the author sees it fit, however, s/he will use 「女忍者」 or 「くノ一」 to refer to a female ninja in fiction.

Comment: I'd be curious to know though if there'd been historical cases of women endorsing the role of a ninja. Or any such legend, just like [Mulan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua_Mulan).

Comment: @Rightleg According to [this](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B01EQQNWSK), [萬川集海](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bansensh%C5%ABkai) briefly mentions the existence of female spies, which is unsurprising, but it's far different from today's stereotypical female ninja.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for the references, it's really enlightening!